# iOS facebook sdk placepicker custom tableview cell

Tags: facebook-ios-sdk

Is there a way to customize cells of tableview that placepicker uses, or just get data of nearby places and use them in my own UITableView?

Comment: Good idea, but seems you can't customize that view. Not 100% sure though